# Removing duplicates. generating new one and new key introduced on an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have an array with a certain structure but I'm targetting a particular field value to check for occurrence in other items.

The array looks like this:

```js
arr = [
       {'fruit': 'banana', 'code': 3},
       {'fruit': 'orange', 'code': 1},
       {'fruit': 'banana', 'code': 1},
       {'fruit': 'pineapple', 'code': 5}
]
```

Now the result I'm expecting is:

```js
new_arr = [
       {'fruit': 'banana', 'code': 3, 'occurrence': 2},
       {'fruit': 'orange', 'code': 1, 'occurrence': 1},
       {'fruit': 'pineapple', 'code': 5, 'occurrence': 1}
]
```

The field I'm trying to target is 'fruit' checking for it occurrence and generating a new array with that occurrence.

This question might seem to be duplicated with some but no!

Comment: What's the key that determines whether it's an occurrence of the same one or not?  Do both `fruit` and `code` have to match?  Or just `fruit`?  And, how do you determine the `code` value in the result if the multiple occurrences have different `code` values as in your example?

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks! I made an update to the question. Sorry for that!

Comment: You still don't say how the `code` value is determined in the result when multiple occurrences have different `code` values?

Comment: the code is just ad a fruit_code not actually something important.

Comment: You're not answering the question.  You have both `{'fruit': 'banana', 'code': 3}` and `{'fruit': 'banana', 'code': 1}`.  How do you determine that the result should be `{'fruit': 'banana', 'code': 3, 'occurrence': 2}` with `code: 3` when you had two different code values in the input?  Are you just taking whatever code value is first?

Comment: @jfriend00 as a summary, I've the fruit code as an identifier, like i could have there `fr001` for banana or `fr0321` for an apple ....

Comment: Sorry you're failing to understand me! The banana all have the same code. In fact all  fruits have a code. That's in case someone enters the wrong string for a fruit, the code should correspond. As a hole, the code is like an alternative for the fruit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using a Map object to keep track of dups for a given key and make the lookup for dups efficient.  And, I've attempted to make it a generalized function that will work off any key of any array of objects:

```js
const arr = [
    { 'fruit': 'banana', 'code': 3 },
    { 'fruit': 'orange', 'code': 1 },
    { 'fruit': 'banana', 'code': 3 },
    { 'fruit': 'pineapple', 'code': 5 }
];

function collectDups(array, key) {
    const items = new Map();
    for (const obj of array) {
        const prior = items.get(obj[key]);
        if (prior) {
            ++prior.occurrences;
        } else {
            items.set(obj[key], Object.assign({ occurrences: 1 }, obj))
        }
    }
    // convert back to array form
    return [...items.values()]
}

console.log(collectDups(arr, 'fruit'));
```

Note: This is a little more efficient than schemes that use `.has()` first because it only has to lookup a value once rather than `.has()` followed by `.get()`.

Note: If `code` values are different for common `fruit` entries (as in your sample input), then this will set the `code` value to be the first one encountered in the array.